# Allow or deny subnet from accessing internal load balancer on GCP

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to explicitly allow (or deny) access from a specific set of IP addresses to internal load balancers in GCP?

I have a VPC that is peered with another VPC, and i would like to allow only access to a set of internal load balancers over the connection.

The load balancer's are in a dedicated subnet, so allowing access to only that subnet would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing access from a peering connection to an Internal Load Balancer is totally feasible as documented in [Using VPC Network Peering](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/internal-tcp-udp-lb-and-other-networks#using-vpc-network-peering).

Regarding the firewall rules in GCP, it's my understanding that you can set the [source IP address (or ranges)](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#sources_for_the_rule).

It might be worth to mention that there are some limitation regarding access to the load balancer. This [Client Access](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal#client_access) document might help as well.